# Bring ios mapview in zoomed in mode during first load

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, html, zooming

Hello i am doing an iOS6 in-house iPad app. On my ViewController i have a scroll view. On that at the bottom left i have a map view (20,594,360,347).Mapview location on my scroll view. I have a get location button. Brings the location correctly in zoomed in mode (it shows my office on the map clearly).Works fine. I save the record and open another one and save this record also. So i have 2 records now. Here is my problem. I open my first record and it brings the map in world view. I can see the annotation of where my office is  and i zoom in... zoom in and i see my office. It doesnt bring the location directly in zoom in mode. I close this 1st record and open 2nd record it brings in the location in zoomed in mode(can see my office). I open first record now, i get zoomed in mode (i can see my office clearly). So how do i get the map view to show my first record the first time in zoomed in mode?

Summary : Opening a saved record for the first time shows the map in world view as against to zoomed in mode.

```
- (void)setMap:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)currentCoordinates{ 
....code
[self.nwMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];

[self.nwMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion extentsRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentCoordinates, 80, 80);
extentsRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.002f;
extentsRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.002f;


[self.nwMapView setRegion:extentsRegion animated:NO];
ITMAnnotation *annotation = [[ITMAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:currentCoordinates addressDictionary:nil];
annotation.title = @"Drag to Move Pin";
annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"subtitle change at 314");

[self.nwMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
self.tempMapView = self.nwMapView;
}
```

What setting should i enable to get the map in zoomed in mode.? If you need more information,please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At what point are you calling `setMap`? If you are doing it before viewDidLoad then you'll be losing all the set up you do to the UI because it hasn't been loaded yet. Once the VC is loaded you can `setRegion` on the map and do what ever. I suspect you are reusing the VC with the second record so it is calling `setRegion` on map that is read to be used.